# Do I need to do something special to use clojure.core/time?

Tags: clojure

I'm calling clojure.core/time which is documented as "Evaluates expr and prints the time it took.  Returns the value of expr"

Eg:

```
(time (expensive))
```

Macroexpanding it shows that it does store the value as a let so after outputting the time it should return immediately with the value in the let expression.

When I make the call however with an expensive computation, I see a delay and then get the time back, but then have to wait for a significant time (sometimes +10 seconds or more) for the result to appear.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

PS: This is using clojure 1.3.0 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you are returning something lazy, of which the elements are only produced when fed to the REPL? In that case, you might want to wrap it in a `dorun` which forces all elements to be produced.

If you could provide the details of your expensive computation, we could see if this is true.

Useful addition from Savanni D'Gerinel's comment:

The proper syntax is probably `(time (doall (computation)))` if you want to return the result and `(time (dorun (computation)))` if you do not.

Comment: This is almost definitely a laziness issue.  I asked a question earlier in which I was profiling an operation, and at first the operation was taking an amazingly short time.  Then I realized that it was not actually being calculated until later.  The proper syntax is probably (time (doall (computation))) if you want to return the result and (time (dorun (computation))) if you do not.

Comment: If that's the case why doesn't time contain a doall? One would expect that if you are timing something you want to know how long it actually takes?

Comment: You are measuring exactly the time it takes what you are doing inside time: constructing a lazy seq, not consuming all elements of the lazy seq (if that is what you are doing, still I don't have your details). "Be explicit about what you want" is a more flexible design than an implicit doall. That's one reason I can come up with, although I didn't design "time" ;).

Comment: You can't put a `doall` inside of `time`, because then you couldn't time anything but lazy sequences. I also agree with the general sentiment of "the current implementation lets you time whatever you want", compared to "you must time how long it takes to realize the whole sequence".

Comment: @amalloy: "because then you couldn't time anything but lazy sequences", that's a damn good point.

Comment: Also, what if you're returning a lazy sequence containing other lazy sequences? You probably want to doall all of them as well; if `time` did some magic for *some* inputs it would be harder to track down the less-common cases.

Comment: One thing I have been noticing is calling `(time (doall (computation)))` works most of the time, however every once in a while I get a delay, a print out of the time and then a further delay where it seems that the computation is still continuing...